# How to resume playing after i sliding the indicator of the slider in my custom moviePlayer?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, iphone-sdk-3.2

In my custom movie player ,i use  `[player setInitialPlaybackTime:playSlider.value];`
to make the movie resume playing at the time i slide to,but it has this situation:
the indicator returns to the start of the movie,then go to the time `playSlider.value` .At the same time, the view of movie get to the starting view of movie then resume the view at the time of `playSlider.value`, playback  after buffering from the starting to the right time i slide to finally.
  Actually,i do not like this situation,i'd like to let the indicator go to where i slide to directly,so does the view,and continue playback after buffering.
 Is there any idea ?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.It needed

```
[player setInitialPlaybackTime:playSlider.value];
    [player stop];
    [player play];
```